# When I tap the TextField and don't show the keyboard. How can i use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am new iOS Application Developer. and I want to try when i tap the `textfield` and don't show the keyboard but `textfield` to tap then show the cursor point will be show. how can i try this?
i want try this code but it did't work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the Function.

and implement the `.h` file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

implement the `.m` file.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (!textField.inputView) {
        //it hides the keyboard, but cursor will show
        textField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: nice description @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

If you don't allow people to tap in TextField, using textfield's delegate method:

```
 (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        return false;
    }
```